# Bash: prevent evaluation of a variable

Tags: bash

I have a variable that stores a directory path,(optionally owner,group), and permissions, separated with a pipe:

```
line='/opt/temp/dir/*|||a+r'
```

If I echo `$line`, I get the directory substring in the way I expect and need:

```
~ /opt/temp/dir/*|||a+r
```

So, now I need do parse this line and assign its directory component to the corresponding variable, something like this:

```
DIR=$(echo $line | awk -F "|" '{print $1}')
```

The problem is that when I echo the `$DIR`, I get the whole list of subdirectories because of `*`.

```
~ # echo $DIR
/opt/oracle/asa_test/a1 
/opt/oracle/asa_test/a2 
/opt/oracle/asa_test/a3 
/opt/oracle/asa_test/test123
```

but I need to get exactly the substring `/opt/temp/dir/*`:

```
 echo $DIR
 ~ # /opt/temp/dir/*
```

As you see the `$line` is evaluated inside the `$DIR` variable.
How can I avoid this and get exactly the first substring into the `$DIR` variable  before the first pipe including `*`?

Comment: quote your variables.

Comment: oh indeed , thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-Quote your variables to avoid `Pathname Expansion` in `bash` as `echo "$DIR"`

From the `man bash` page,

> Pathname Expansion
>
> After word splitting, unless the `-f` option has been set, bash scans each word for the characters `*`, `?`, and `[`.  If one of these characters appears, then the  word  is  regarded  as  a  pattern,  and
>          replaced  with  an  alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern.

Comment: This is correct, but it would be useful to demonstrate exactly when to quote and which quotes to use.  eg `echo "$DIR"`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks! Updated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `awk` for this simple task:

```
line='/opt/temp/dir/*|||a+r'
echo "${line%%|*}"
```

---

If you want to split the string at the `|` characters, use:

```
IFS='|' read -r -a fields < <(printf '%s|\0' "$line")
```

This will populate the array `fields` with the fields of your string:
the command `declare -p fields` will output:

```
declare -a fields='([0]="/opt/temp/dir/*" [1]="" [2]="" [3]="a+r")'
```